# Unwanted right and left borders of the tds of a table in Firefox after hide()/show() from jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, border

I am having a weird behaviour from Firefox (not IE neither Chrome).

I have a table with alternate rows being hidden with JQuery. These hidden rows have some TDs with right or left border while there is no borders on the visible rows.

When I click the button to display the hidden row, no problem. But if I unfold several in a row Firefox gives the same right and left border of the extra raws to the always-visible rows that are in-between.

If I use the button that display all the rows in once, there is no problem: no extra right and left borders on the other rows.

I don’t know if I am clear.

Comment: What do your HTML and JavaScript code look like? Those would be helpful for understanding the problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. You are right, it would be better with the code but there's quite a lot and I don't really see what part to select. I was just hoping someone encounter the sqme odd behaviour. For the moment, I just remove the borders but it's frustrating... Thanks anyway

Comment: If you're able to cut it down to a smaller version that duplicates the problem, that's frequently a good place to start.  If it really does take a large amount of code to reproduce, well, sometimes that happens too. :-)